# Ruby on Rails 4: valid? always returns true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use validators on my class, to validate information on my API. But it always returns true, when I call valid?

Do you have any idea why? I'm using Rails 4.

```
class Address
   include ActiveModel::Model
   include ActiveModel::Validations
   include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods

   attr_accessor :street

   validates :street, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 100 }
end

address = Address.new
address.street = 'aa'
address.valid? (returns true)
```

Comment: do you get error when you do address.save! ?

Comment: @Vishal, I get undefined method `save!'

Comment: @Vishal It is not ActiveRecord, but ActiveModel. So `.save` is out of question.. no?

Comment: Indeed, @ArupRakshit

Comment: @HenriqueGuarnieri No problem I see.. [link](https://pastebin.com/yEEFjkFB).

Comment: @ArupRakshit, would be there any difference in Rails 4?

Comment: @ArupRakshit okay got your point.

Comment: @HenriqueGuarnieri No problem in 4 .. [link](https://pastebin.com/dhWMiByw)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'm using this code inside a controller, I don't know why it is happening :(

Comment: Can you stop the server, and then do `spring stop`.. and restart the server again.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with the provided code with 4.2.0, 4.2.7, or 5.2.0; are you seeing the problem if you run this code in a "clean" project? is there something else where in your project that might be contributing to the issue?

Comment: Thanks, guys! I transfered the class to the same file and now it works, probably was some cache.

Comment: @HenriqueGuarnieri Ok cool..

Comment: Where was it previously then?

Comment: Actually there was two problems: cache and the usage of ActiveModel::Validations and include ActiveModel::Model, if I use both, my validators doesn't work and always return true for valid?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this using Rails 4.2.10.  Maybe you need to upgrade to Rails 4.2.latest???

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.10)

Frame number: 0/5
[1] pry(main)> class Address
[1] pry(main)*   include ActiveModel::Model   
[1] pry(main)*   include ActiveModel::Validations   
[1] pry(main)*   include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods   
[1] pry(main)*   
[1] pry(main)*   attr_accessor :street   
[1] pry(main)*   
[1] pry(main)*   validates :street, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 100 }   
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> {:length=>{:minimum=>10, :maximum=>100}}
[2] pry(main)> a = Address.new
=> #<Address:0x00007fb728c42b10>
[3] pry(main)> a.street = 'aa'
=> "aa"
[5] pry(main)> a.valid?
=> false
[6] pry(main)> a.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fb728bafce8
 @base=#<Address:0x00007fb728c42b10 @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fb728bafce8 ...>, @street="aa", @validation_context=nil>,
 @messages={:street=>["is too short (minimum is 10 characters)"]}>
```